# Самодур — кто это такой?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Человека, облеченного властью и использующего эту власть в угоду собственных, порой самых бредовых желаний, называют самодуром.
Интересно было бы узнать, что это за слово. Напрашивается аналогия — "сам дурак".
Но речь ведь не о глупом человеке, а о том, кто злоупотребляет властью.
Тогда почему все-таки он — самодур?

Answer (score 3):

> Толковый словарь Ушакова
> "Самодур - это называется, коли вот человек никого не слушает, ты ему хоть кол на голове теши, а он всё своё." А. Островский. (Слово стало в ходу после комедий Островского.)

Добролюбов в своей знаменитой статье "Темное царство" (1859), описывая героев Островского, много раз употребил это звучное слово, фактически пустив его во всеобщее пользование.
Первое упоминание *самодура* в русской литературе :

> Н.А. Полевой. Иоанн Цимисхий (1841)
> Сатрап ― наместник правителя в восточных странах; в дальнейшем ― деспот, **самовольный, ни с чем не считающийся правитель, самодур.**

Поскольку *самодур* невольно сравнивался или соотносился с *самодержцем*, то в Словаре 1847, а тем более в САР 1789-94 такого слова нет, не включили по понятным причинам.
Даль приводит такие пояснения :

> **Самодур** м. самодурье ср. глупый и
> самоуверенный, затейливый, упрямый человек.
> Самодурь ж. балмочь, бестолочь.
> Он сделал это самодуром , самодурью , по-своему и притом глупо.
> Самодурить, дурить в свою голову,
> упрямиться.

(14.10.14)
Нашел статью В.В.Виноградова, где очень подробно история слова рассмотрена.
http://wordhist.narod.ru/samodur.html
Небольшое извлечение :

> Однако в русском литературном языке XVIII в. слово самодур было известно, хотя и не в значении человека упрямого, действующего по прихоти и произволу. Например, у Д. И. Фонвизина в письме к гр. Н. И. Панину из заграницы в 1772 г.: «Хотя, в самом деле, за будущее ручаться невозможно, однако турецкое изнеможение, вступление австрийцев в общее с нами согласие и самая справедливость дела нашего подает причину надеяться, что мир заключен будет по положенному основанию, **каким бы самодуром** на конгрессе поступлено не было»347. Ср. в романтической драме А. А. Шаховского «Двумужница, или за чем пойдешь, то и найдешь» (в речи слепого нищего Саватия): «...какая жена не захочет взять волюшку? благо, ей дают, да и **кто на этом свете от самодура упасется?**» (СПб., 1836, с. 142).
>
> Очевидно, что здесь слово самодур употребляется в значении орудия и способа действия: `собственная прихоть, произвол, немотивированное неожиданное побуждение'.
>
> Такое употребление слова самодур замерло в русском литературном языке к 30— 40-м годам XIX в. Действительно, слово самодур не найдем ни в одном русском толковом словаре XVIII в. и первой половины XIX в. Правда, в «Опыте областного великорусского словаря» указывалось слово самодур, но со значением `самовар' Перм. Ирбит. (с. 197).

Answer (score 2):

САМОДУР, Человек, действующий по произволу, по собственной прихоти, не считаясь с другими людьми.

Самодуром не назовут человека, самостоятельно принимающего правильные решения. Вот пример:  "Любит свою работу, но вообще-то  редкостный самодур:  авторитарен,  единственная цель ― кем-нибудь руководить; но  это у него плохо выходит, поскольку он не знает людей и чаще всего промахивается, недооценивая окружающих и партнеров".

Поэтому самодур непременно "дурит", но дурит самостоятельно, не прислушиваясь к мнению окружающих.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Пожалуй, стоит еще отметить креативность самодура, то есть творчество ему отнюдь не чуждо, однако  у окружающих оно вызывает исключительно негативную оценку.

Answer (score 0):

Есть же слова "самодержец", "самовластный" и др. Думаю, отсюда.

Как это называется-то... Снижающая параллель, что ли?